# Dual-monitor – dialog boxes appear on "wrong" screen

Tags: dual-screen

At home I work regularly between two monitors – I have a Dell monitor connected to my MacBook Pro. It's not something I've done a whole lot until recently so I was trying to find a solution to the problem that when I'm working in an application on the connected monitor, how can I always have the dialog boxes for that application open on that monitor, and vice versa? It's pretty annoying and definitely slows down work a bit, especially if an application open on the other monitor is in full screen.

Comment: I have scoured the web again and only find people pleading for an answer. Someone has to have an idea what is wrong, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open System Preferences - Display, then click on Arrangement, you will see a white bar above one of the displays. This is where the menu bar is and will be the primary display and probably the screen that the dialogue boxes are opening on. To change just drag it across to the other screen in the Arrange window and this should then make the dialogue box appear on that screen.

Comment: OP's not talking about Notification Center pop-ups. OP means dialog boxes within apps, which do sometimes appear on the wrong screen in multi-monitor setups.

Comment: I tried this and it solved the problem with the dialogs

Comment: The problem is that it is never "solved". It happens to multiple software systems, so it is a Mac/Windows problem with dual monitors, not the problem of a specific system. Also, it is erratic. That is, the first click drops down the menu on the secondary monitor (where it should), the second one drops it back to the primary (laptop) monitor and also in very small size. Extremely annoying, and questions all over the web. No solutions found to date.